# Can I have map of Star Wars galaxy showing territory of Separatists and commercial routes?

Tags: star-wars

I have seen lots of Star Wars maps (official and fan-made both), but none of them show clear boundary between The Galactic Republic and Separatists (yes, I am talking about The Clone Wars period).

Also, there are conflicts over Hyperspace Lanes. There are also privately owned routes (just heard about it from friends; not confident).

Is there any official version of a map showing both (preferably free)?

Comment: You'll want to buy a copy of Star Wars : The Essential Atlas

Comment: Sure. That’ll be $20.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The images below are taken from the [Star Wars: The Essential Atlas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas). As of April 2014, this is no longer considered a fully canon source of information about the Star Wars universe, but it's the best you're likely to see.

[image]

[image]